# chmod configuration in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, chmod, privacy

I am attempting to restrict access to a few backend folders in an elastic beanstalk environment, but I cannot figure out how to set chmod permissions in an existing environment.

I am aware that there may be a way to do this through the .ebextensions file, but I have been unable to find a resource outlining this process.

How do I restrict folder access to folders and files in my elastic beanstalk environment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting you can use in the .ebextenstions file called "files". I haven't tested this with folders though and I am not sure if you can change permissions on already existing files and folders with it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files

You could just add a command that does it though.

```
    commands:
      01_set_file_permissions:
        command: "chmod 600 /path/to/file"
```

Comment: How do we know what /path/to/file is?  What directory is our app deployed to?

Comment: It depends on what environment you are using. Python for example is deployed to /opt/python/current which is a link to /opt/python/bundle/<bundle_version>/.